# Running old code on new flutter and dart version

Tags: windows, visual-studio, flutter, dart

I abandoned a project I was working on for a while I came back to open it on upgraded flutter and dart plugin in visual studio code windows 10.now I get so many problems. is there a way to automatically update code to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is it depends.

Judging by the comments from a reasonably good answer by Hasan Abbasi, this wasn't enough.
Depending on how old your project is, there are 2 choices before or after doing what that answer said:

1. If it's any more than 2 or 3 years old, I'd probably rewrite it from scratch. In that time, Flutter and Dart have matured greatly, which involves many breaking changes. Also, null-safety has been introduced. Creating a new project after updating Flutter will also fix those Gradle issues because the configuration files will be reset.
2. If it's less than that, try to fix those Gradle issues either by hand or just deleting the '/android' or '/ios' etc. folders and letting Flutter/Dart automatically recreate them when you run the app next. You'll probably need to migrate to null-safety: read about null-safety so you understand it properly, then try using the [`dart migrate` tool](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide). You will likely need to spend some time changing dependencies for null-safe versions. Then you can try the [`flutter fix` tool](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix) to automatically resolve SOME issues.

Hope you can get your app to work soon!

Answer (score -1):

do these steps:

1. delete `build` folder
2. delete `.idea` folder
3. run `flutter clean`
4. run `flutter pub get`
5. run `flutter pub upgrade`

then try to run your project.

Comment: followed your steps and got errors running without debug. process exception error,  org.gradle.wrapper and many more gradle related errors.

Comment: please share the errors so I can check precisely.